# How to execute a function from another UIViewController in the UIViewController where was created

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 UIViewControllers: ProductsVC and CartVC. In CartVC I have a function which is clearing all my products from my cart.
What I want to do is when I am in the ProductsVC and I delete a product from the CoreData then to clear all my products from the second VC which is CartVC. So I need to tell to that function to be executed there.

Here is my code:

```
// First VC
class ProductsViewController: UIViewController{

    // Function to delete a Product from the table view and also from CoreData
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let productEntity = Constants.productEntity
        let managedContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let product = productsArray[indexPath.row]
        // -----------   HERE I NEED TO TELL TO "clearAllProducts()" to be executed in the CartVC so when I click on the Cart button, there will be 0 products.
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            managedContext.delete(product)
            do {
                try managedContext.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(Constants.errorDeletingProduct + "\(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }

        // fetch new data from DB and reload products table view
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: productEntity)
        do {
            productsArray = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Product]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(Constants.errorFetchingData + "\(error.userInfo)")
        }
        productsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}


// Second VC
class CartViewController: UIViewController {


// Clear all products from the cart
    @IBAction func clearAllProducts(_ sender: Any) {

        // Reset Cart tableView
        productsInCartArray = [Product]()
        productPricesArray = [Float]()
        totalSum = 0
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[1].badgeValue = String(0)

        // Remove selected products from ProductsViewController
        ((self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! ProductsViewController).selectedProductsArray = [Product]()
        ((self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! ProductsViewController).priceForSelectedProductsArray = [Float]()
        ((self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! ProductsViewController).counterItem = 0
        ((self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! ProductsViewController).numberOfProductsInCartLabel.text = String(0)
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        cartTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Here is a picture so see why I want to do that:

[image]

Thank you for your time !

Comment: how is productVC and CartVC are associated ? Does productVC presents/pushes CartVC or productVC is a container and CartVC is rendered as childVC in it? In any case u can have reference to CartVC and call method directly on it

Comment: Both ViewControllers are connected with a TabBarController like in this picture: https://ibb.co/bRqTpy

Comment: you just need one global variable of view controller in you vc from where you want to invoke methods of their vc

Comment: I don't want to use Globals....is a bad practice.

Comment: how its bad practice

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1:
If one of your view controllers is invoked by the other one, then you can have a delegate property in the invoked VC and assign the value of the delegate to the first view controller and just normally call the delegate methods. e.g. `self.delegate?.myFunc()`

2:
If your view controllers are not directly related, then you may use `NotificationCenter` to send notifications to all of the listening views. **In your case this one is probably more suitable.**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem with a small function which is instantiate my arrays with empty values. The function is this one:

```
// Remove all products from the cart when one ore more products are deleted from the CoreData.
func removeAllProductsFromCart(){

    selectedProductsArray = [Product]()
    priceForSelectedProductsArray = [Float]()
    counterItem = 0
    numberOfProductsInCartLabel.text = String(0)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[1].badgeValue = String(0)
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

I call this function here:

```
if editingStyle == .delete {
    managedContext.delete(product)
    do {
        removeAllProductsFromCart()
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(Constants.errorDeletingProduct + "\(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to share data is to have a custom tab bar controller and your arrays should be a property of the tab bar.

That way both VC’s have access to the data and can clear it as needed using a custom method of the tab bar controller.